# Visual c++ project with multiple cpp files : _main is already defined

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i have several .h files and .cpp files that i've created using DOS c++ compilers.
Now i want to use them in a Visual c++ project.
I have included all my .h files.
Now , when i have included my first cpp file , is working correctly.
But when i have included my second .cpp file , and try to run  i've get an error : _main is already defined.

What can i do ? I want ( !! don't know if possible !!) to have several .cpp file inside the same project and run them separately.

Is this possible ?

Comment: How many `main` functions are there in your files? And how do you "include" your cpp files? It will all be clearer if you take the time to read about and post a [mcve].

Comment: on every cpp files there is a main

Comment: *Of course* you can compile multiple source files as part of a single project. You don't seriously believe that projects like Chromium or the Linux kernel, that are millions of lines of code, are all in a single source file, do you?

Comment: Well you can only have one `main` - that's the idea of it. Of course you can have multiple cpp files, but they are supposed to have different functions in them, not all the same.

Comment: @Aganju Sorry , i have several cpp files that i have running ok using DOS compilers , now i want to have a solution in Visual c++ and to be able to run all my cpp files. What can i do ?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Ok friend , don't joke with a beginner. I need some little help ,.i have several cpp files that i have running ok using DOS compilers , now i want to have a solution in Visual c++ and to be able to run all my cpp files. What can i do ?

Comment: If you have multiple individual programs, all with their own `main`, that you want to combine into one program. Then you need to get rid of all the individual `main` functions and in their place, implement *one* which somehow takes care of figuring out what sub-program you want to run and then calls the right function for that (probably a renamed main from the original program). You will need to change your code to support a structure like this. You can't just dump all the files into a single project and expect it to work.

Comment: One program, one project. Joker. They can live in the same solution though.

Comment: Do you want to create multiple executables or one executable?  For multiple executables, create multiple *solutions* with Visual Studio, one for each executable.